# How can change the name of the modal header of Vue js Bootstrap modal window?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

```
<div>
  <b-btn v-b-modal="'productModal'" class="more_details_button" @click="chooseProduct(product)" product_item="'product'">More Info</b-btn>
</div>
```

```
<b-modal v-if="chosenProduct" hide-footer="true" ok-title="Buy Now" modal-title="{{ chosenProduct.Name }}">...</b-modal>
```

This what I have above. I would like to change the name of the modal's title.  `chosenProduct()` is one of my methods and `Name` is a column in my database. I am not sure how I could represent one of the data elements from my database in the field of `modal-title`. I have tried binding it, like `:modal-title="chosenProduct.Name"` but it doesn't seem to do anything. Would appreciate some help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The header is title in bootstrap-vue

```
<b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue">
   <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
</b-modal>
```

You can make it reactive using v-bind

```
<b-modal id="modal-1" v-bind:title="chosenProduct.Name">
   <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
</b-modal>
```

Or shorter

```
<b-modal id="modal-1" :title="chosenProduct.Name">
   <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
</b-modal>
```